# Is it possible to query for posts you voted on, while logged into the Stack Exchange Data Explorer?

Tags: support, voting, data-explorer

I was writing [a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/145507/user-reputation-excluding-reputation-earned-on-a-certain-tag?Tag=regex&UserId=925913) that involves calculating all reputation gained and lost by

- my question being upvoted (+5),
- my question being downvoted (-2),
- my answer being upvoted (+10),
- my answer being downvoted (-2),
- my answer being accepted (+15),
- me upvoting someone's question (0) **(NOT EXPOSED)**,
- me downvoting someone's question (0) **(NOT EXPOSED)**,
- me upvoting someone's answer (0) **(NOT EXPOSED)**,
- me downvoting someone's answer (-1) **(Exposed?)**,
- me accepting someone's answer (+2).

As I understand, `Votes.UserId` is kept `NULL` (*i.e.* not exposed) except for `VoteTypeId = 5` (*i.e.* favorites, which *are* exposed). However, being logged in, is it possible to get SEDE to return data regarding *my* votes? (If not, would this be a feasible feature request—exposing `Votes.UserId` for the user that's logged in?)

Comment: No, you can't get your own votes.

Comment: I think data explorer and stack exchange log ins are seperate, so logging in as "you" is not sufficient as its not the same you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not exported in the Data Explorer, but you can see them from your own profile:

```
$SITEURL/users/{id}/?tab=votes&sort=downvote // to fetch the posts you have downvoted
$SITEURL/users/{id}/?tab=votes&sort=upnvote // to fetch the posts you have upvoted
```

For you, the `{id}` will be [**925913**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/925913/?tab=votes&sort=downvote) on Stack Overflow.

There is no other way (as far as I'm aware) for you to get this data for someone else.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll have to calculate the rep lost on downvotes manually.