# Finding my upvotes on Data Explorer

Tags: support, voting, data-explorer, up-votes, api

This T-SQL finds all the questions I  have answered on SO.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1779459/questions-i-have-answered

I want to determine if I upvoted the question or not (as I wish to UV **ALL** questions that I have answered).

I can't see an appropriate column

[Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede)

nor an applicable API.

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs

Comment: "upvote all questions that I answered" - don't. Vote based on question quality. Blind voting, may it be up or down votes, is the worst thing one can do.

Comment: As for my downvote, it's because I don't want to give you tools to help in something that is bad for Stack Exchange, or bad in general.

Comment: These older questions seem a bit related: 
[Is it possible to query for posts you voted on, while logged into the Stack Exchange Data Explorer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204285), 
[Query to get questions I voted on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51931)
and [Possible to search questions I voted on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48830).

Comment: If you didn't upvote the question at the time, when you had all the time in the world to carefully consider the question and decide whether it merited an upvote, even think about it enough to write a proper answer - **why on Earth** do you think you should upvote it now, mindlessly?

Comment: related on MSO: [How can I determine when I cast a specific upvote?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424692/11107541), [How to find how many votes I have cast on one user's posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406520/11107541)

Answer (score 15):

Votes are anonymous by design so there's no public record of your (or anyone else's) votes. If you upvoted a post you'll have to log in and check on the site itself via the votes tab in your profile.

I'm not sure that upvoting all questions you've answered is a good criteria for upvoting. You're supposed to upvote questions that show research effort, are useful and clear. I suppose if you managed to answer it, it may be clear and you may have checked the other criteria when you answered it but if you didn't, you should before voting.